# Search result files needs to be looped through

Tags: excel, vba

The code written below searches file with the user provided name and shows it in a message box. Can it be stored in a array so that when it is required , the search result files can be opened and looped to read the content of the search result files

---

```
 Private Sub cmdsubmit_Click()

 If Me.PART_NUMBER.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please enter the Part Number.", vbExclamation, "PART SEARCH"
    Me.PART_NUMBER.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
 End If


 If Me.ID_TAG.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Select a ID TAG.", vbExclamation, "PART SEARCH"
    Me.ID_TAG.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
 End If

 Call flist

 End Sub

Sub flist()



Dim myList
Dim fldr As String, fltr As String, sTemp As String, sHldr As String
Dim i As Long
Dim msg As String
Dim FileCount As Integer

  FileCount = 0



fldr = "C:\Users\op\Desktop\New folder"
If Right$(fldr, 1) <> "\" Then fldr = fldr & "\"
fltr = (Me.PART_NUMBER.Value & "*.xls")

msg = fltr & " files found:" & vbLf
sHldr = Dir(fldr & fltr)
Do While sHldr <> ""
    sTemp = sTemp & "|" & sHldr
    sHldr = Dir
Loop
If sTemp <> "" Then
    myList = Split(sTemp, "|")
    For i = 1 To UBound(myList)
        msg = msg & vbLf & myList(i)
    Next i
Else
    msg = msg & vbLf & "None"
End If
MsgBox msg


End Sub
```

Comment: If in your actual code you have the "End Sub" like Andy pointed out, try going through the code step by step using F8. This way you can check the values of different variables to see if and how things are skipped.

Comment: the search code written should find the file as when i tested it earlier with fltr as the file name i wanted to search it used to return the file as found but now i changed it to Fltr = Me.Part_Number.Value and it is unable to find files which is given by the user as input...is that the wrong way of connecting user input to my search code. the search result is unable to find the file from the given directory path and returns as no file found.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have lost your `End Sub`'s.

You can either copy the code between (but not including) `Sub fList()` and its `End Sub` to the end of the first code (just before its End Sub) or use

```
Call fList
```

again, before the End Sub of the Click event.

**Added** The user would have to enter `thefile.gif` or `thefiles.*` in order to find files using `Dir`. If they enter `something` as the PART_NUMBER it is looking for a (single) folder of this name, or a file of this name (without an extension).

**Added** In response to further comment. If the user enters "1" as the PART_NUMBER then your code will find files that begin with "1", which is a string. It you want to find files that begin with any number then you'll have to write the code that constructs these filenames, in a loop:

```
For x = 1 to 800
```

If they enter "banana1" and you want to find all files "banana1", "banana2" then you'll need to remove the "1" from the end of the text and, again, look for the files in a loop. You could reduce the amount of looping by looking for "banana1*", "banana2*", etc..

Comment: Thanks mason and Andy...I did use End Sub at the end of my original code but missed it here....This time the call works but the search result is unable to find the file from the given directory path and returns as no file found

Comment: the search code written should find the file as when i tested it earlier with fltr as the file name i wanted to search it used to return the file as found but now i changed it to Fltr = Me.Part_Number.Value and it is unable to find files which is given by the user as input...is that the wrong way of connecting user input to my search code...

Comment: Also i reedited the code for correct picture of my work ..Thank you

Comment: I've added to my answer, but you should also learn how to debug your code. Add a `Breakpoint` to a line by pressing F9 and then step through the code by pressing F8. Point at variable names as you step through to see what value they have.

Comment: thanks it did work after i used extension .xls ..thank you for help.

Comment: The search results generated by the code does not includes all the files having the particular part number . The files range from 1 to 800, instead of including all of it . It only returns files like 1,10,100,101-109,11,110-116.  why is that happening and why isn't it returning all files from 1-800. kindly help!!